# The convexity of the smoothed version of a convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I recently read Flaxman et.al's paper ['Online convex optimization in the bandit settings: gradient descent without a gradient'](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0408007.pdf). They proposed a smoothed version of the function f, such that:
$$\hat{f}(x) = E_{v\in B}[f(x+\delta v)]$$

where $\delta$ is a fixed number, $v$ is a unit vector randomly selected from the unit ball $B$

My question is if f(x) is a convex function, how to prove the smoothed version, $\hat{f}(x)$, is convex? Any help could be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then
$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y + \delta v ) = f(\lambda (x+\delta v) + (1-\lambda)(y + \delta v )) \le \lambda f (x + \delta v) + (1-\lambda) f(y + \delta v)$.

Now take expectations of both sides and used linearity.

Comment: thank you so much!